# Handlebars.js -- convert flat list to hierarchical list

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a project which uses Handlebars.js to transform some source JSON from one layout to another layout.  Within the source JSON, one data point is stored as a flat list in a pre-sorted order.  I need to convert this to a hierarchical list wherein each member of the list is a child object of the previous item, as laid out below.

I've tried a recursive function within an {{#each}} loop but that errored out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**USING HANDLEBARS.js, GO FROM THIS:**

```
{"people_list": ["dave", "bob", "bill", "joe", "sarah"]}
```

(a simple ordered list with no parent/child node relationship data available, and of arbitrary length)

**TO THIS:**
(each name in the list becomes a child object of the previous object)

```
{"itemtext": "dave",
    "childobjs": 
        [
            {"itemtext": "bob",
                "childobjs": 
                    [
                        {"itemtext": "bill",
                            "childobjs": 
                                [
                                    {"itemtext": "joe",
                                        "childobjs": 
                                            [
                                                {"itemtext": "sarah"}
                                            ]
                                    }
                                ]
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
}
```

**USING ONLY:**
an {{#each people_list}} loop and/or whatever Handlebars helpers we either already have or can write.

**edit**
I'm starting to think that the best approach is a Helper that takes the people_list as a parameter and hands back the finished json structure, something like:

```
{{build_hierarchy people_list}}
```